# Unable to run Apache nifi docker container in swarm. Empty response

Tags: docker, apache-nifi, docker-swarm, docker-stack

I am unable to run official nifi image in docker swarm.
When I start container in regular mode:

```
docker run --name nifi -p 8080:8080 -d apache/nifi:latest
```

everything works fine and I can access the application under http://localhost:8080/nifi

However when i try to run application in docker swarm:

```
docker swarm init
docker stack deploy -c docker-compose.yml nifi
```

With the following docker-compose.yml

```
version: "3"
services:
  zookeeper:
    hostname: zookeeper
    container_name: zookeeper
    image: 'bitnami/zookeeper:latest'
    environment:
      - ALLOW_ANONYMOUS_LOGIN=yes
  nifi:
    image: apache/nifi:latest
    ports:
      - "8080:8080" 
    expose:
      - "8080"
    environment:
      - NIFI_WEB_HTTP_PORT=8080
      - NIFI_WEB_HTTP_HOST=localhost
      - NIFI_CLUSTER_IS_NODE=true
      - NIFI_CLUSTER_NODE_PROTOCOL_PORT=8082
      - NIFI_ZK_CONNECT_STRING=zookeeper:2181
      - NIFI_ELECTION_MAX_WAIT=1 min
```

Application starts (zookeeper and nifi) but is unaccessible under http://localhost:8080/nifi

```
curl http://localhost:8080
curl: (52) Empty reply from server
```

However running the following code:

```
docker exec -it 629ecd6949d9 curl -v http://localhost:8080
```

shows that nifi is up and running, but for some reason it does not work from outside container.

I am close to start hitting the wall with my head. How can I fix this?

Best
Paweł

Comment: For future:
resolution was to set:- NIFI_WEB_HTTP_HOST=0.0.0.0

Comment: It seems only works in container running on a single host. If container deploy across hosts it won't work.

Answer (score 2):

Refactored your compose file. Try to use it:

```
version: "3.3"
services:
  zookeeper:
    hostname: zookeeper
    image: 'bitnami/zookeeper:latest'
    environment:
      - ALLOW_ANONYMOUS_LOGIN=yes
  nifi:
    image: apache/nifi:latest
    ports:
      - target: 8080
        published: 8080
        protocol: tcp
        mode: host 
    environment:
      - NIFI_WEB_HTTP_PORT=8080
      - NIFI_WEB_HTTP_HOST=0.0.0.0
      - NIFI_CLUSTER_IS_NODE=true
      - NIFI_CLUSTER_NODE_PROTOCOL_PORT=8082
      - NIFI_ZK_CONNECT_STRING=zookeeper:2181
      - NIFI_ELECTION_MAX_WAIT=1 min
```

Comment: It seems only works in container running on a single host. If container deploy across hosts it won't work.

Answer (score 0):

In order to make the NiFi image run in Docker swarm mode you need to add `NIFI_WEB_HTTP_HOST=0.0.0.0` to the environment section of the docker-compose file:

```
version: "3"
services:
  zookeeper:
    hostname: zookeeper
    container_name: zookeeper
    image: 'bitnami/zookeeper:latest'
    environment:
      - ALLOW_ANONYMOUS_LOGIN=yes
  nifi:
    image: apache/nifi:latest
    ports:
      - "8080:8080" 
    expose:
      - "8080"
    environment:
      - NIFI_WEB_HTTP_HOST=0.0.0.0  # This line right here

      - NIFI_WEB_HTTP_PORT=8080
      - NIFI_WEB_HTTP_HOST=localhost
      - NIFI_CLUSTER_IS_NODE=true
      - NIFI_CLUSTER_NODE_PROTOCOL_PORT=8082
      - NIFI_ZK_CONNECT_STRING=zookeeper:2181
      - NIFI_ELECTION_MAX_WAIT=1 min
```

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, if NIFI_WEB_HOST=0.0.0.0 then it will cause problem when nifi container try to communicate with each other.

[image]
[image]

```
    2020-02-20 03:20:13,509 WARN [Replicate Request Thread-5] o.a.n.c.c.h.r.ThreadPoolRequestReplicator
java.net.SocketTimeoutException: timeout
        at okio.Okio$4.newTimeoutException(Okio.java:232)
        at okio.AsyncTimeout.exit(AsyncTimeout.java:285)
        at okio.AsyncTimeout$2.read(AsyncTimeout.java:241)
        at okio.RealBufferedSource.indexOf(RealBufferedSource.java:355)
        at okio.RealBufferedSource.readUtf8LineStrict(RealBufferedSource.java:227)
        at okhttp3.internal.http1.Http1Codec.readHeaderLine(Http1Codec.java:215)
        at okhttp3.internal.http1.Http1Codec.readResponseHeaders(Http1Codec.java:189)
        at okhttp3.internal.http.CallServerInterceptor.intercept(CallServerInterceptor.java:88)
        at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:147)
        at okhttp3.internal.connection.ConnectInterceptor.intercept(ConnectInterceptor.java:45)
        at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:147)
        at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:121)
        at okhttp3.internal.cache.CacheInterceptor.intercept(CacheInterceptor.java:93)
        at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:147)
        at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:121)
        at okhttp3.internal.http.BridgeInterceptor.intercept(BridgeInterceptor.java:93)
        at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:147)
        at okhttp3.internal.http.RetryAndFollowUpInterceptor.intercept(RetryAndFollowUpInterceptor.java:126)
        at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:147)
        at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:121)
        at okhttp3.RealCall.getResponseWithInterceptorChain(RealCall.java:200)
        at okhttp3.RealCall.execute(RealCall.java:77)
        at org.apache.nifi.cluster.coordination.http.replication.okhttp.OkHttpReplicationClient.replicate(OkHttpReplicationClient.java:138)
        at org.apache.nifi.cluster.coordination.http.replication.okhttp.OkHttpReplicationClient.replicate(OkHttpReplicationClient.java:132)
        at org.apache.nifi.cluster.coordination.http.replication.ThreadPoolRequestReplicator.replicateRequest(ThreadPoolRequestReplicator.java:647)
        at org.apache.nifi.cluster.coordination.http.replication.ThreadPoolRequestReplicator$NodeHttpRequest.run(ThreadPoolRequestReplicator.java:839)
        at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: java.net.SocketException: Socket closed
        at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:204)
        at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:141)
        at okio.Okio$2.read(Okio.java:140)
        at okio.AsyncTimeout$2.read(AsyncTimeout.java:237)
        ... 28 common frames omitted
```